# How to run Windows 8 Phone emulator on Proxmox VM?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

There are VM setting for VMPlayer to run Windows 8 Phone emulator, Are there any available for Proxmox?

Comment: Don't quite get it. I think you can install Windows 8 in VM, then you can run WP8 Emulator. Right?

Comment: WP8 requires hardware virtualization and some other stuff. There are settings in VMWare to do that. I'm interested in what it would take to run it on Proxmox.

Comment: can't you use VMPlayer or Hyper-V ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use nested virtualization for this. It depends on your hardware if nested virtualization is supported and if it can be enabled in KVM on your Proxmox Host.

You cannot activate nested virtualization via GUI, you have to do it via commandline and your have to do everything by hand.

In Proxmox's own documentation wiki, there is a draft article about this:

https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Nested_Virtualization